Database to be connected to a google sheet file
We are a family office, and our beneficiaries prefer using Google Sheets. We have built our reporting system within Google Sheets, where each month we create a new file for all cash flow transactions, mapping, and performance calculations. The outputs from these monthly reports are consolidated into a single input for a main summary file, where P&L, Balance Sheet, Cash Flow, and performance metrics can be viewed on a monthly basis since inception.
The challenge we’re facing is that our main file has reached Google Sheets' 10 million cell limit, so we are now exploring alternative solutions like Addepar, Solovis, Qplix, and others. However, these options are costly and don’t fully meet our needs. We believe our current reporting system is superior, with the exception of the cell limit issue.
Our question is: Is there a database solution (preferably by Google) that can store all our monthly cash flows and balances, which can then be easily and seamlessly connected to our main Google Sheet file without time lags?

Why not separate it into multiple sheets?

I would recommend that you use Google Cloud.
You can choose between Firestore, Cloud SQL, etc. which can be connected to your Google Sheets using Apps script. However, if you are not familiar with using scripts. I would highly recommend BigQuery as it can directly incorporate your existing Google Sheets, plus it is a pay as you go model.
These are the Google Cloud databases that I could think of that can be beneficial to your use cases of your existing Google Sheets.  You can also utilize the 300$ free trial of Google Cloud while finding what’s best fit for your needs. What's great with it is the free tier services that could hugely help you minimize the cost even after your free trial period, especially that some Google Cloud databases are covered with it. E.g. BigQuery which you can be free of use up to TB of querying per month and 10 GB of storage each month.
You can check these public documentation for your references:

Google Cloud Databases
Free tier usage limit
Free cloud features and trial offer
Google Cloud BIgQuery
BigQuery to Google Sheets
Analyze & refresh BigQuery data in Google Sheets using Connected Sheets

